# Средствами sql вывести N строк другой таблицы как N столбцов

Tags: sql, запрос

Есть таблица **exams(exam_id)**, есть таблица **photos(photo_id, exam_id, photo)**. В среднем, на один экзамен приходится три фотки. Хочу странного, исключительно средствами sql вывести табличку **(exam_id, photo1, photo2, photo3, ..., photoN)**. Хотя, вполне устроит вариант из трех photo.

Подскажите, куда смотреть.
Благодарю

Comment: Читать как работает `pivod` транспонирование таблиц

Comment: Читал. Как я понял, pivot работает с агрегирующими функциями, что мне не совсем подходит

Comment: Если без pivod всёравно прийдётся агрегирующии функции ставить, наример `max(case when photo_id=1 then photo end)  photo1` и так далее. Без агрегации никак.

Comment: В вашем случае у вас идет групировка по exam_id, а остальное собирается агрегацией либо pivod.  Например так `select  exam_id, max(case when photo_id=1 then photo end) photo1 /*etc*/ from photos group by exam_id`

Comment: А если photo_id -- первичный ключ с инкрементом. Т.е. для одного exam_id - 43, 44, 45, а для другого уже 51, 54, 58

Comment: Тогда делайте нумерацию подзапросом (функция row_number), и присоидиняйте согласно номера.

Comment: Оно! Благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT exam_id, max(CASE WHEN num=1 THEN photo ELSE null END) photo1, max(CASE WHEN num=2 THEN photo ELSE null END) photo2, max(CASE WHEN num=3 THEN photo ELSE null END) photo3 FROM (SELECT exam_id, row_number() over(partition BY exam_id ORDER BY photo_id) num, photo FROM photos ORDER BY exam_id) t GROUP BY t.exam_id;
```

Собственно, спасибо  nick_n_a за наводку.

Если кто-нибудь выложит вариант с PIVOT, плюс в карму.